# Problem with my hangman game

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to learn python and I'm attempting a hangman game. But when I try and compare the user's guess to the word, it doesn't work. What am I missing?

```
import sys
import codecs
import random

if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        wordlist = codecs.open("words.txt", "r")
    except Exception as ex:
        print (ex)
        print ("\n**Could not open file!**\n")
        sys.exit(0)

    rand = int(random.random()*5 + 1)
    i = 0

    for word in wordlist:
        i+=1
        if i == rand:
            print (word, end = '')
            break

    wordlist.close()

    guess = input("Guess a letter: ")
    print (guess) #for testing purposes

    for letters in word:
        if guess == letters:
            print ("Yessssh")

#guessing part and user interface here
```

Comment: What is your code doing wrong? What doesn't work?

Comment: Not sure what your specific error is, but here are some tips on refactoring this:
-Use random.randint() instead of random.random()
-To get the list of words, you can just use open("words.txt","r").readlines()
-instead of the last for loop, you an just say "if guess in word"

Comment: I second RexE's comment. Your code works just fine for me. Can you elaborate on what isn't working? Is there an error message, or is it a question of unexpected output?

Comment: woops sorry, yeah I got my answer from laurence but it was an error of unexpected output with the for letters in word loop

Comment: OK. By the way, from your code style I'm guessing that you come from a Java (or related language) background. As you get more familiar with Python's idioms, you'll be pleased with how concise and clear you can make your code :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In your "`for word in wordlist`" loop, each word will end in a newline. Try adding `word = word.strip()` as the next line.

By the way your last loop could be replaced with:

```
if guess in word:
    print ("Yessssh")
```

Bonus tip: when adding "debug prints", it's often a good idea to use repr (especially when dealing with strings). For example, your line:

```
print (guess) #for testing purposes
```

Might be more useful if you wrote:

```
print (repr(guess)) #for testing purposes
```

That way if there are weird characters in `guess`, you'll see them more easily in your debug output.

Answer (score 0):

This is what i did for my hangman game:

```
     for x in range(0, len(secretword)):
           if letter == secretword[x]:
                for x in range(len(secretword)):
                    if secretword[x] in letter:
                         hiddenletter = hiddenletter[:x] + secretword[x] +hiddenletter[x+1:]

     for letter in hiddenletter:
          print(letter, end=' ')
```

secretword is the hidden word that the user is trying to guess.
hidden letter contains the amount of "_" in the word:  i.e. hiddenletter = " _ " * len(secretword)

this replaces the blanks with the correctly guessed letters and then shows the underscores with the letters in the right places
i did my best...